# tikz tree node on edge always above the line, not just on it

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, labels

I am building attack trees for my bachelor thisis. And i need to connect some children nodes by a logical and operator. So i just drew a line between thoses nodes, and put a node on it.

Sadly I am not able to make the label of the edge to be put directly on the (hidden) line, its always midway above it. And i have no idea why... Hope you can help me.

Heres a minimal example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,headsepline,dvipsnames,bibliography=totocnumbered]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}

\usetikzlibrary{trees}

\begin{document}

    \tikzset{
        attackTree/.style={
            auto,
            font=\small,
            edge from parent fork down,
            level distance=2.5cm,
            every node/.style=
            {   rectangle,
                minimum height=15mm,
                minimum width=30mm,
                draw=black,
                align=center,
                text depth = 0pt
            },
            edge from parent/.style=
            {   draw=black}
        },
        treeOperator/.style={
            minimum width=0,
            minimum height=0,
            draw=none
        }
    }

    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        attackTree,
        sibling distance=35mm
        ]
        \node {Open safe}
        child{
            node {Pick lock}
        }
        child{node {Learn combo}
            child{node {Find written\\combo}}
            child{node {Get combo\\from target}
                child{node{Threaten}}
                child{node{Blackmail}}
                child{node{Eavesdrop}
                    child{node(listen){Listen to\\conversation}}
                    child{node(state){Get target to\\state combo}}
                }
                child{node{Bribe}}
            }
        }
        child{node {Cut open safe}}
        child{node {Install\\improperly}};

        \draw[draw=none] (listen) -- (state) node[treeOperator,midway] {$\wedge$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And this is what it looks like:
[image]

I Just want the logical and operator centered right on the hidden line. There must be an option in my settings, which prevents it from beeing where it should be, but I am not able to figure out, which one it is.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Add `auto=false` to the `TreeOperator` settings: `treeOperator/.style={...,auto=false}`.

Answer (score 2):

As @esdd mentioned:

> add `auto=false` to the `TreeOperator` settings: `TreeOperator/.style={...,auto=false}`. –

did the trick and solved my problem. Thank you :)